# Align text in an asp:TextBox

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, text-align

I have a textbox that displays a text from a sql query but I want to align it to the right.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGvCosto" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Bind("CostoCasetas", "{0:c}") %>' BorderColor="Transparent" 
     BackColor="Transparent" OnTextChanged="TxtGvCosto_TextChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="true" />
```

This is the column

[image: This is the column]

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: Just add a CSS rule: `table input[type=text] { text-align: right; }`, however a **better** solution is to ditch `<asp:TextBox>` (because it's horrible, ancient, and smells worse than my late grandmother's late pet cat's breath) and use `<input type="number" />` instead.

Comment: @Dai A `<asp:TextBox>` with `TextMode="Number"` will render an `<input type="number">`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming TIL, thank you. But even so, that doesn't exonerate WebForms' from its mile-long list of other sins on the web...

Comment: You mean like the much lower learning curve of webforms? you mean like how mvc jobs in the market place is poor? You mean like the new adoption rate of asp.net is falling? You mean all that? And now you telling people to leave the asp.net system? (bad advice). We need to KEEP the asp.net community or asp.net will continue to die a slow death. And now we go and find + use a 3r party gird control? (like everyone else has to - then might as well just drop using asp.net then, right?). And that means the help for say grids is now forked into multiple choices (no help on SO then, right?).

Comment: Increase the cost of butter, or web development = less consumption and jobs for that platform, and that's exactly what MVC did.  I would suggest we encourage the ease of use of webforms, get new people hooked on asp.net, and THEN they can make the transition to mvc. But, I would not public chase away potential asp.net users as you doing here. The problem is MVC requires a LOT more work, and lot more learning curve - as a result, I might as well go out and use PHP or something else, right? We simply can't keep advising and chasing away users from the asp.net ecosystem - we losing the user base

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal WebForms is dead. Your argument is invalid.

Comment: web forms aint dead even classic asp still runs.  Try putting it in a TD then style text align=right

Comment: @Dal  No, if they are to keep uptake of the asp.net eco system alive, that means we need to keep  and introduce asp.net to a new user base. That is not occurring right now.  If you have a better solution to this problem, then share it with the readers here - but chasing them away from asp.net is not the answer. As I stated - you increase learning curve and cost of development? (which MVC does), then you increase costs of entry into that platform, and that IS EXACLTY what has occurred and is occurring now.  The result is now low uptake of asp.net - NOT good, not good at all.